# FullCalendar list view - how to hide "all-day"

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a FullCalendar List view.

All of the entries in the view will always be "all day" events. Therefore I don't really need the "all-day" that appears in the left column. Is there a way to remove this from the list?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(

  function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('date_list');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'list' ],
        defaultView: 'listThirtyDay',
        height: 'auto',
        views: {
            listThirtyDay: {
                type: 'list',
                duration: { days: 30 },
                buttonText: '30 days'
            },
            listDay: { buttonText: 'Day' },
            listWeek: { buttonText: 'Week' }
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'listDay,listWeek,listThirtyDay',
        },
        time: false,
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: $('.KeyDatesURL').val()
            }
        ]
    });
    calendar.render();      
  } 
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the rendered HTML elements using your browser's Developer Tools you'll see the time text in a List view is kept inside a HTML element with the class "fc-list-item-time".

Therefore you can set a simple CSS rule to hide it:

```
.fc-list-item-time {
  display:none;
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRJByop

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
allDaySlot: false
```

See this link here - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/allDaySlot

also you can refer this:
[How to remove allDay from view in fullcalender JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178369/how-to-remove-allday-from-view-in-fullcalender-js)

Comment: `allDay: false` only applies to TimeGrid views, but the question is showing a List view. Also, if it _was_ possible to remove the all-day from a List view, it would remove all of the events. OP only wants to remove the text "all-day", not the whole events!

Answer (score 0):

*(*Fullcalendar versions 5 + 6)*

If you simply hide the area that contains the text 'all-day' - you prevent the utilization of that area completely. If you wish to continue to utilize the space where the 'all-day' text is - you could use the method below.

You can utilize **'eventDidMount'** function and JQUERY to target the area that holds the text **'all-day'**

```
eventDidMount: function(object) {

   // remove 'all-day' text
   $(object.el).children(':first-child').text('');

   // continue on with other customization
   $(object.el).children(':first-child').append("<img src='img/icons/my_image.png' style='width: 24px;'>");
    
});
```